# Revalidate dependant inputs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-validation

I have a form with two inputs. The first one is the current working directory and the second one is a file name. I use angular ui validate to create custom validation rules that checks if the directory exists and the file exists within this directory. It works great but I would like to revalidate the file name input when I change the working directory. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Here is a simplified code :

```
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error' : config.workingDir.$invalid, 'has-success' : config.workingDir.$valid}">
        <label for="workingDir" class="control-label">Working directory</label>
        <input id="workingDir" class="has-feedback form-control" ng-model="configuration.workingDir" type="text" name="workingDir" ui-validate="'existingDir($value)'" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error' : config.robotFile.$invalid, 'has-success' : config.robotFile.$valid}">
        <label for="robotFile" class="control-label">Robot description file</label>
        <input id="robotFile" class="has-feedback form-control" ng-model="configuration.robotFile" type="text" name="robotFile" ui-validate="'existingFile($value)'" required>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: on-change of the directory you can check the file exist or not

Comment: Yes I can check it but it will not change the validation state of the file name input

Comment: you can use $watch and register your model watch is working any time when you change the input

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @Ahmer I know how to listen for changes but I don't know how to trigger the validation of the other input

Comment: @neda I updated my post.

Comment: You can set config.robotFile.$invalid to true once you check that file is not present in the directory

Comment: @neda I could do this but it would lead to code duplication. I would check if the file exists in the on-change event and in the in-validate. It would be better just to trigger the validation in the on-change.

Comment: In the in-validate of the directory you can also keep a check that if a file name is there then check if file exists or not

Comment: would it be easier to trigger a "change" event on the filename ?